# Can the Return URL within forms link to an external url?

Tags: freeform, plugin-amforms, plugin-expressforms

I'm building a form and would like to either have the "submit" button drive to an external URL, or to a page on my site that redirects to an external URL. I can't find a way to make this work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can control the URL that the browser sends form requests to using the [`action` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-action). If you leave this attribute empty or don't include it at all, the request will just go to same page (URL) the form is on. But you can point it to an external URL as well:

```html
<form method="POST" action="https://example.com/path/to/form/submissions">
    <!-- … -->
</form>
```